# CKEditor display HTML content only

Tags: html, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

Is it possible to force CKEditor 4.x to display HTML code only, disabling design mode completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CK Editor has a config.js file:

```
../ckeditor/config.js
```

Add:

```
config.startupMode = 'source';
```

and remove `source` button in `toolbars` setting